# Node - Exception thrown when inserting into MongoDB (byte array)

Tags: node.js, express, request, node-https

I'm getting the error in my Express + NodeJS app. I'm using an API from CoinAPI.io, and I've had an issue in the past with getting a Byte array as a response from the API. I've looked into the issue and I resolved it in the past with a `Buffer.concat`, so I can send the front end a json object as a response. Code below:

```
app.get('/build', function(req, res){
    console.log('Building the database...');

    // make client connect to mongo service
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("SUCCESS: Database created");
        let dbo = db.db('lab5');

        // Craft request header
        const options = {
            "method": "GET",
            "hostname": "rest.coinapi.io",
            "path": "/v1/assets",
            "headers": {'X-CoinAPI-Key': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'}
        };

        // Send request to CoinAPI.io
        const request = https.request(options, response => {
            let chunks = [];
            response.on("data", chunk => {
                chunks.push(chunk);
            });
            response.on('end', () => {
                let json = Buffer.concat(chunks);

                // Insert into the database
                dbo.collection('crypto').insertMany(json, function(insertErr, insertRes) {
                    if (insertErr) throw insertErr;
                    console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + insertRes.insertedCount);
                    db.close();
                });
                console.log('End of request stream')
            });
        });

        request.end();

        // print database name
        console.log("NOTE: db object points to the database : "+ db.databaseName);
        db.close();
    });
    res.end();
})
```

This worked before, but now I have to instead insert the data I retrieve into a MongoDB database. So, I try to do an `insertMany` on the `body` object I'm creating out of the `Buffer.concat`. But now I get the following error.

```
MongoError: docs parameter must be an array of documents
```

I did a `console.log(json)` before the collection insert, and body dumps into the console the byte array that I *just* did the concat on, and I don't know why.

EDIT: In response to Sohail about using `.toJSON()`, this is what happened when I tried to convert the buffer to json

```
let buf = Buffer.concat(chunks);
let json = buf.toJSON();
console.log(json);
```

And when I console log json...

```
{
  type: 'Buffer',
  data: [
     91,  10,  32,  32, 123,  10,  32,  32,  32,  32,  34,  97,
    115, 115, 101, 116,  95, 105, 100,  34,  58,  32,  34,  78,
     80,  88,  83,  34,  44,  10,  32,  32,  32,  32,  34, 110,
     97, 109, 101,  34,  58,  32,  34,  80, 117, 110, 100, 105,
     32,  88,  34,  44,  10,  32,  32,  32,  32,  34, 116, 121,
    112, 101,  95, 105, 115,  95,  99, 114, 121, 112, 116, 111,
     34,  58,  32,  49,  44,  10,  32,  32,  32,  32,  34, 100,
     97, 116,  97,  95, 115, 116,  97, 114, 116,  34,  58,  32,
     34,  50,  48,  49,
    ... 5165802 more items
  ]
}
```

and I still get the error of inserting a byte array/buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `Buffer` object to `mongo document` object. 
You could use `buffer.toString()` method and then parse it with `JSON.parse` method to convert `string` to `object`.

Try this.

```
let buf = Buffer.concat(chunks);
let json = JSON.parse(buf.toString());
// Insert into the database
dbo.collection('crypto').insertMany(json, function (insertErr, insertRes) {
    if (insertErr) throw insertErr;
    console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + insertRes.insertedCount);
    db.close();
});
console.log('End of request stream');
```

Comment: that did it! Thanks!